# Can I flush all pending onDraw calls

Tags: java, android, drawing, android-drawable, flush

I was using [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) to try and make something draw on the screen... but `invalidate()` says:

> onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future

So I guess I could find some way to call the `onDraw()` myself, but does Android offer any sort of flush function that can be used here?

Searching around so far the only thing I found was the [`flushable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Flushable.html) class, but I'm not sure if that can be leveraged somehow.

Comment: I doubt. As you already know the UI Thread is responsible for the UI, Touch Events etc, and if I am not mistaken all those events are queued. So you would like to clear this queue to give priority to your invalidate, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Have you check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to see if it helps?

Comment: @blackbelt - Yeah, that's pretty much what I was looking to do. I'm surprised Android doesn't provide any methods to query/manipulate the queued events, I assumed I just hadn't found how to do it yet